# Magento CE 1.9.3.0 sales_order.info returns no Order Items

Tags: sales-order, soap, magento-community

I found out that calling sales_order.info via SOAP in CE 1.9.3.0 does not return Order Items. Instead I only get something array-like:

`<items SOAP-ENC:arrayType="ns1:salesOrderItemEntity[1]" xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderItemEntityArray">
    <item xsi:type="ns1:salesOrderItemEntity"/>
</items>`

In CE 1.9.2.3 you definitely get all order items back. Is this a bug or how can you retrieve the order items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: There is a new function which induces a array to string conversion error. It is: `Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract::processingRow()`

There you can see:

```
/**
 * Prepare Api row data for XML exporting
 * Convert not allowed symbol to numeric character reference
 *
 * @param $row
 * @return mixed
 */
public function processingRow($row)
{
    $row = preg_replace_callback(
        '/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]/u',
        function ($matches) {
            return '&#' . Mage::helper('core/string')->uniOrd($matches[0]) . ';';
        },
        $row
    );
    return $row;
}
```

But in order to handle that correctly it should be:

```
/**
 * Prepare Api row data for XML exporting
 * Convert not allowed symbol to numeric character reference
 *
 * @param $row
 * @return mixed
 */
public function processingRow($row)
{
    if (is_array($row)) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $entry) {
            $row[$key] = $this->processingRow($entry);
        }
    } else {
        $row = preg_replace_callback(
            '/[^\x{0009}\x{000a}\x{000d}\x{0020}-\x{D7FF}\x{E000}-\x{FFFD}\x{10000}-\x{10FFFF}]/u',
            function ($matches) {
                return '&#' . Mage::helper('core/string')->uniOrd($matches[0]) . ';';
            },
            $row
        );
    }

    return $row;
}
```